# Ionic Capacitor Deploy App on ios 13.3 device freeze splashscreen

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

After I have run the latest update on my iphone and then want to deploy the app to my iphone using XCode, the app is started on the iphone and then the splash screen freezes. In XCode the following is displayed:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB53AC39-F58D-47D4-8860-273E51D8171B/App.app/App
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB53AC39-F58D-47D4-8860-273E51D8171B/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB53AC39-F58D-47D4-8860-273E51D8171B/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB53AC39-F58D-47D4-8860-273E51D8171B/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB53AC39-F58D-47D4-8860-273E51D8171B/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB53AC39-F58D-47D4-8860-273E51D8171B/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB53AC39-F58D-47D4-8860-273E51D8171B/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB53AC39-F58D-47D4-8860-273E51D8171B/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB53AC39-F58D-47D4-8860-273E51D8171B/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.framework/Capacitor: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Xcode or CocoaPods.

Free Apple dev accounts can't run apps on real devices if they use some CocoaPods frameworks (such as Capacitor, but it's affecting a lot of more).

So the only solution for now is to pay for an Apple dev account or use the simulator.

You can also try to remove `use_frameworks!` from `ios/App/Podfile` and run `npx cap sync ios`, but not sure if some other thing will break.

Comment: This answer seems correct.  I get the capacitor error then after switching over to our paid developer account it works perfectly.

Comment: First of all thank you for your help! 
But I can't quite understand it, because before I updated my iphone to ios 13.3.1, I was able to deploy the app to my iphone without any problems

Comment: I just tried it out. I'm afraid it doesn't work. Then I'll have to use a developer's license. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I don’t know why only happens on iOS 13, but happens on a lot of projects that use CocoaPods, such as flutter, nativescript, capacitor or Alamofire among others

Comment: So no solutions to run an app without paying on a real device?

Comment: get an iOS 11-12 device, other than that, not possible at the moment

Answer (score 1):

On the 24th of March Apple released iOS 13.4. This update includes a fix for the code signature issue! Please refer to the iOS 13.4 beta 3 for more information.

Comment: yeah! Works! Thank you!